# Read text from ASP Label Control (populated by jquery)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, css, asp.net

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
      var items = [];
      $.each($("input[name]:checked"), function() {
        items.push($(this).val());
      });
      //alert("You entered: " + items.join(", "));
      if (items.length === 0) {
        $('#<%=Label1.ClientID%>').html("No data to display.");
      } else {
        items = items.join(", ");
        $('#<%=Label1.ClientID%>').html("You selected the following options: " + "<br />");
        $('#<%=txtTestVar1.ClientID%>').html(items);
      }
    });
  });
</script>

<button type="button" runat="server">Update Choices <i class="fas fa-retweet"></i></button>
<br />
<br />
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="txtTestVar1"></asp:Label>
```

```html
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { lblNotification.Text = txtTestVar1.Text.ToString(); }
```

I populate a label on the html page using Jquery and that works well. However when I'm trying to read from that label (by using the code behind - c#) that was just populated, its returning an empty string. Anybody can explain why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text/value of a label doesn't get included in the postback payload data.

You'll have to store the data in a `HiddenField` (or `TextBox`) instead of a `Label`, eg.

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="txtTestVar1"></asp:HiddenField>
```

and at client side set the data via jQuery `val` instead of `html`.

```
$('#<%=txtTestVar1.ClientID%>').val(items);
```

At server side you get the value via the hidden fields `Value` property.

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    var value = this.txtTestVar1.Value;
    // ...
}
```